# Facebook auth is broken for home screen webapps!+

Tags: javascript, iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook

Facebook connect.js js api cannot work with a home screen webapps when using meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" (to remove all mobile safari ui)

After it authenticates I am left with a white screen, I guess because it can't navigate back to the app screen.

The code works fine in every desktop browser & mobile safari.

Any solutions that work with http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js?

EDIT: In my search I've found this question a few times on the fb boards. No one has voiced a good solution yet, even a closed bug with no helpful info http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15512

Answer (score 0):

the white screen is an error with redirection - it's an xd_proxy.php call, can you confirm? 
If so, you must update your connect.js code to the newest avaliable, and it will start to work again.